# Find end of sentence/paragraph with regex

Tags: regex

Semi new to regex I have one that finds the phrase between a keyword and end of sentence:

http://regex101.com/r/sD1lU8/1

however I want it to find the phrase even if the line ends with a paragraph etc and not go on to find the rest of the document looking for a sentence:

http://regex101.com/r/sD1lU8/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
keyword?(?<CAPTURE>[^.\n]{1,300})
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sD1lU8/4